# How to use startParameters in BuildGradle task?

Tags: gradle

I would like to pass `deployDir` (with value `/my_archive`) to `uploadArchives` task in `my_project`:

```
task build (type: GradleBuild) {
        buildFile = './my_project/build.gradle'
        tasks = ['uploadArchives']
        /* startParameter =  [deployDir:"/my_archive"] ??? */      
}
```

I do not know how to declare the start parameters. I have tried different ways, e.g.,

```
startParameter = [deployDir:"/my_archive"]
```

Without success.

How to declare [startParameter](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html) in the GradleBuild task?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume you mean to pass the `deployDir` as a [project property](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties). In this case, you'll find there is a [`setProjectProperties(Map)`](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#setProjectProperties%28java.util.Map%29) method you can use:

```groovy
task build (type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = './my_project/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['uploadArchives']
    startParameter.projectProperties = [deployDir: "/my_archive"]
}
```

This will enable you to access `deployDir` as a variable from the called build script:

```groovy
uploadArchives {
 repositories {
  mavenDeployer {
   repository(url: deployDir)
   // --- or, if deployDir can be empty ---
   repository(url: project.properties.get('deployDir', 'file:///default/path'))
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we can set the project properties and system properties via the api

```
setProjectProperties(Map<String,String> projectProperties)  
setSystemPropertiesArgs(Map<String,String> systemPropertiesArgs)
```

here is the sample from my local for startParameter:

```
task startBuild(type: GradleBuild) {
StartParameter startParameter = project.gradle.startParameter;

Iterable<String> tasks = new ArrayList<String>();
Iterable<String> excludedTasks = new ArrayList<String>();

startParameter.getProjectProperties().each { entry ->
    println entry.key + " = " + entry.value;

    if(entry.key.startsWith('t_')){
        tasks << (entry.key - 't_');
    }

    if(entry.key.startsWith('build_') && "true" == entry.value){
        tasks << (':' + (entry.key - 'build_') +':build');
    }

    if(entry.key.startsWith('x_') && "true" == entry.value){
        excludedTasks << (entry.key - 'x_');
    }
}

startParameter.setTaskNames(tasks);
startParameter.setExcludedTaskNames(excludedTasks);

println startParameter.toString();
}
```

we can reference the api from this link [StartParameter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html)

the startparameter is really powerful in gradle when you need to customize your gradle build logic.